# SQL Numerator from 0-Z

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a simple an elegant way to create a numerator in SQL the do the following:

- Three digit number
- Each digit can can have a number from 0-Z : Min 000, Max ZZZ
- for example let's take : 129, After increasing by 1, the new number will be 12A
- When number is 15Z, after increasing by one it will turn into 160 and so on.

I can only use SQL, no code behind !!.
I only need an enumerator and not a conversion between bases like other have suggested.

Can someone help me write a UDF.

I got an excellent and elegant answer which I marked below.

Who ever marked my question as negative please reconsider because this is a real problem and not a theoratic one and it saved me a lot of workarounds.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use a number that ranges from 0 - 46655 and then convert to base-36 in your presentation layer?

Comment: I can only use SQL and no code behind at all.

Comment: You'd have to write a UDF that calculates the next value.   There is nothing built in to SQL that will do this automatically.

Comment: I know I have to write a UDF, can you help me with that

Comment: Maybe you can get away with http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/03/22/sql-server-enumerations-in-relational-database-best-practice/

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: the blog of SQL authority is a great blog however it does not relate to the problem above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Produce cartesian and take the first that is greater then input value:

```
declare @v varchar(10) = '129'

;with cte as(select * from (values('0'),('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9')
                                 ,('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G'),('H'),('I'),('J'),('K')
                                 ,('L'),('M'),('N'),('O'),('P'),('Q'),('R'),('S'),('T'),('U'),('V')
                                 ,('W'),('X'),('Y'),('Z')) t(n))
select top 1 c1.n + c2.n + c3.n as n
from cte c1
cross join cte c2
cross join cte c3
where c1.n + c2.n + c3.n > @v
order by n
```

Comment: This is probably the best looking approach, however it does not return the correct value for 1ZZ

Comment: It returns 200 for me. I think this is correct, isn't it?

Comment: It returns 1AA for me

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, hmmm that is very strange. Are you sure you copied the code correctly?

Comment: This is because of my collation. Still looking for a fix

Comment: Thanks for the elegant and CORRECT answer which I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should store the values numeric and then convert them when needed to your format.

Here is a script to add one to the strange format. The script is not checking for overflow nor invalid data in the original value:

```
DECLARE @original char(3) = '129'

DECLARE @val int = 
  CASE WHEN RIGHT(@original, 1) > '9' THEN ASCII(RIGHT(@original, 1)) - 55
    ELSE RIGHT(@original, 1) END
  +CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@original, 2,1) > '9' 
    THEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(@original, 2,1)) - 55 ELSE SUBSTRING(@original, 2,1) END * 36
  +CASE WHEN LEFT(@original, 1) > '9' 
    THEN ASCII(LEFT(@original, 1)) - 55 ELSE LEFT(@original, 1) END * 36 * 36
  +1 -- increase 1

SELECT 
  CHAR(CASE WHEN @val / 36 / 36 > 9 THEN @val / 36 / 36 + 55 
            ELSE @val / 36 / 36+48 END)+
  CHAR(CASE WHEN (@val / 36) % 36 > 9 THEN (@val / 36) % 36 + 55 
            ELSE (@val / 36) % 36+48 END)+
  CHAR(CASE WHEN @val % 36 % 36 > 9 THEN @val % 36 % 36 + 55
            ELSE @val % 36 % 36+48 END)
```

Result:

```
12A
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create this table in your DB with this query

```
 ;WITH Ch AS
 (  select i,C=CASE WHEN i<=10 THEN Char(47+i) ELSE CHAR(54+i) END FROM (SELECT TOP 36 row_number() over(order by object_id) i  from sys.objects) t  )

SELECT row_number() over(order by Ch.c,Ch2.c,Ch3.c) i,
Ch.c + Ch2.c + Ch3.c C INTO B36 FROM Ch CROSS JOIN Ch Ch2 CROSS JOIN Ch Ch3
```

So you can do indexes in the i & C columns
Then you do queries from this table for conversions with index seeking fastest speed and optimized as follows:

```
SELECT C FROM B36 WHERE i=3728
```

Reverse encoding with

```
SELECT i FROM B36 WHERE C='AG7'
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a converter like this:

```
char(48 + (i / (36 * 36)) + CASE WHEN (i / (36 * 36)) > 9 THEN 7 ELSE 0 END) + 
char(48 + (i / 36) % 36 + CASE WHEN (i / 36) % 36 > 9 THEN 7 ELSE 0 END) + 
char(48 + i % 36 + CASE WHEN i % 36 > 9 THEN 7 ELSE 0 END)
```

that can convert an `int` value to what you want.

**[[`SQL Fiddle Demo`]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3dd6a/2)**

---

**Edit**

I also can give you inversion of above converter like this:
(E.g.: `@t varchar(max) = '12Z'`)

```
(ASCII(LEFT(@t, 1)) - 48 - CASE WHEN ASCII(LEFT(@t, 1)) > ASCII('9') THEN 7 ELSE 0 END) * 36 * 36 +
(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@t,2,1)) - 48 - CASE WHEN ASCII(SUBSTRING(@t,2,1)) > ASCII('9') THEN 7 ELSE 0 END) * 36 +
(ASCII(RIGHT(@t, 1)) - 48 - CASE WHEN ASCII(RIGHT(@t, 1)) > ASCII('9') THEN 7 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: Your solution does not take into account the fact that the input can be a non numeric value such as 15Z like I have given i my question.

Comment: @Scription - but as I've said, you *really*, *really* ought to be storing the *data* (Which is just a number in the range 0-46655) and the *presentation* (which, if you insist, can be added as a computed column). There is really no sane reason to treat the *representation* in base-36 as the basic data.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion hoe ever I need an enumerator and not a conversion between bases

Comment: You can use inversion to get int then return base36 with converter ;).

Answer (score 0):

Function that converts bigint to Base36

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnBase36
(
    @Val BIGINT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(13)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(13) = ''

    IF (@Val <= 0)
    BEGIN
        RETURN '0'
    END

    WHILE (@Val > 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Result = CHAR(@Val % 36 + CASE WHEN @Val % 36 < 10 THEN 48 ELSE 55 END) + @Result,
               @Val = FLOOR(@Val/36)
    END

    RETURN @Result
END
GO
```

> select dbo.fnBase36(321)
>   --returns 8X

Comment: Your solution does not take into account the fact that the input can be a non numeric value such as 15Z like I have given i my question.
I need the select dbo.fnBase36('129') will return 12A and select dbo.fnBase36('13Z') will return 140